# airflow can not use Local Filesystem Secrets Backend

Tags: airflow

I want to store connection in local files in dev context. I use docker compose to run airflow. I try this [guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/local-filesystem-secrets-backend.html) and have a local file `conn.json` :

```json
{
  "CONN_A": "mysql://host_a",
  "CONN_B": {
    "conn_type": "scheme",
    "host": "host",
    "schema": "schema",
    "login": "Login",
    "password": "None",
    "port": "1234"
  }
}
```

I have mounted this file in the container in `docker-compose.yaml` :

```yaml
  volumes:
...
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config/conn.json:/opt/airflow/files/conn.json
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/config/var.json:/opt/airflow/files/var.json
```

And also in the `ariflow.cfg`, I have updated the [secrets] section :

```
[secrets]
backend = airflow.secrets.local_filesystem.LocalFilesystemBackend
backend_kwargs = {"variables_file_path": "/files/var.json", "connections_file_path": "/files/conn.json"}
```

But when I run airflow, the connections are not added :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connections ARE added, but don't show in GUI. I can't find the link in airflow documentation but I read that.